# Loop through class properties?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class ("Names"):

```
Option Explicit

Public companyName As String
Public companyCode As String
Public companyCountry As String
Property Get fullInfo() As String
    fullInfo = "Code " & companyCode & " is " & companyCountry & " for " & companyName
End Property
```

and in a Sub() in a Module, I have the following:

```
Sub classTest()

Dim c1 As New Names
Dim c2 As New Names
c1.companyCode = 14
c1.companyCountry = "Ivory Coast"
c1.companyName = "Ivory Company"
c2.companyCode = 11
c2.companyCountry = "Cameroon"
c2.companyName = "Cameroon Company"

Dim i As Integer

debug.print c1.fullInfo

End Sub
```

This correctly will print "Code 14 is Ivory Coast for Ivory Company".

How can I write a loop to go through ALL the properties (is that the right word? is c1, c2, a 'property'?).  I tried something like below, but it didn't work:

```
for i = 1 to 2
 debug.print ci.fullInfo
next i
```

You can see that it obviously won't work - but how can I get it to do so? Sorry, I don't know what the c1 part is called, nor what's the part after the . is called)

Comment: I know I can do an array - I'm trying to learn other things.  It looks like I would want to do a collection, so I can still keep those "keys"... whereas in an array, I couldn't use a key to pull out only the "companyCountry" - I would have to know that's stored in array(x,2) part or something.

Comment: Quick tutorial: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s239/collections.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store c1,c2,etc in an array or collection then you can loop over them using a standard For loop and call fullInfo for each of them.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim col As New Collection, n As Names, i

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set n = New Names
        n.companyCode = i
        n.companyCountry = "Country_" & i
        n.companyName = "Company_" & i
        col.Add n
    Next i


    For Each n In col
        Debug.Print n.fullInfo
    Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Ooh, thanks - collections look like what I'm trying to get to.

Answer (score 1):

Look at a **for each** loop.  Something like

```
For Each variable_name In collection_name
   'Some code here.
Next variable_name
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work as I have my code - it looks like I need to make a collection first.  I'll create a collection, and this'll work.  Thanks!